# Why did Hades defend Zeus' statue?

Tags: clash-of-the-titans-2010

In [*Clash of the Titans (2010)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800320/), if man's worship feed the god's power then when the statue was ripped down it weakened Zeus. Why then did Hades attack the men who defiled it if his endgame was to weaken (and eventually overthrow) his brother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two reasons:

1. He needs humans' fear, as he admitted to "have only learned to live on their fear" (while Zeus need their love), so the short term reason is to get as much of their fear as possible.
2. As for the long term reason, he is plotting against Zeus, but is not yet strong enough (I mentioned that [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/14025/5589)), so he needs the pretense of supporting Zeus, until his own powers grow.

   Hades' plan is revealed at the end:

   > Hades: Argos has fallen. Do you feel stronger, brother? You thought the Kraken would bring you their prayers. But the Kraken is my child. It feeds only me.
   >
   > Zeus: I command Olympus! Remember who you serve!
   >
   > Hades: I serve myself! I have since you cheated me. You sent me to the underworld to be hated, while you basked in their love.
   >
   > Zeus: We need the love of humans!
   >
   > Hades: No, you need it. I survive on their fear. Your reign is over, brother Zeus. You'll watch while my blessed avenger devours their hopes. And then finally you'll know my pain.

   If Zeus was aware of it in the beginning, or even suspecting a foul play on Hades' part, he'd stop him while he still could. So, Hades played on "I do it for you, brother" card, and got Zeus to comply (and allow him to release the Kraken).